# What magnetic capability is possible?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, electromagnetism

Magneto is way over-powered, even for a mutant. With the given relation between electricity and magnetism, what could be possible?  here is already study work on [biomagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomagnetism), we know the nervous system is electric and the blood contains iron, so there is iron [moving in an electric field](http://www.cs.stedwards.edu/chem/Chemistry/SCI20/Science2320/physics/relation.html).
Assuming at least twice the iron content found in normal blood, and a change in physiology to have eel strength ([500v DC or such](http://www.zotzelectrical.com/ElectricEel.htm)) nervous system, how close could one get?

I did not tag this [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) because I do not need a numeric answer, but I would like to see supporting details for any answer given.

**EDIT:** I am aiming for the ability to attract iron and repel magnets.  Such an ability when used on iron could only attract, and you would need loadstone or something with fixed poles before you could get repulsion.

Comment: For the future, [tag:hard-science] answers don't necessarily have to be based on numbers at all, just firm, indisputable scientific principles and evidence. Also, here's a cool related article: http://io9.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-getting-magnetic-finger-imp-813537993.

Comment: Do you mean humans, or animals in general?

Comment: HDE you are everywhere on here.  I am focusing on humans for this question.

Comment: @HDE226868 Your io9 link appears to be down already.

Comment: @MBurke That's . . . troubling. I'll see what I can do. Is this better? http://io9.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-getting-magnetic-finger-imp-813537993. Hm, no. From SE it doesn't work.

Comment: @MBurke I can tell you whatever you want to know about getting a magnetic implant. I've had one for just over five years now. Alternatively, [this article](http://gizmodo.com/5895555/i-have-a-magnet-implant-in-my-finger) is alright.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "magnetic capability" ? Get a direction from the magnetic field of Earth ? Being a walking magnetic field detector  ? Influence a compass Geller-style ? Stick cutlery to your body ? Create strong magnetic fields from a distance like Neo getting his sais ?

Comment: You need high concentration of ionic solution circulating thoughout your body really fast, that's homo-dynamo!

Comment: btw since you're looking for high voltage of 500V walk around a room this way you will be collecting electrons and your body stores as much as 25000V.(no worry taser(50000V) don't kill, but high current(100mA-200mA) do)

Comment: @Thorsten I am aiming for the ability to attract iron and repel magnets.  With the movie Pacific Rim they did the math, then ignored it when necessary for theatrics. I am looking for a ballpark guess for this ability, without actually making it a magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Iron in blood and high voltage don't matter.**

Magnetic field generation depends on current, not voltage. There is very little current flow in any animals, be it the nervous system or a defence mechanism. Electric eels produce very little current, despite a high voltage.

The iron in blood is not magnetic ([nor is it even ferromagnetic](http://www.revisemri.com/blog/2006/mri-blood-iron-attraction/)), and besides it's *charge flow* (amperage) that creates magnetic fields, not magnetic material flow.

So, existing creatures (even with a doubling or iron and high voltage abilities) are a long way off from developing magnetic abilities. The best bet is to be one of those insane people (I have been one for over five years now) and implant a small magnet in your hand. You can then lift paperclips and bottle caps as well as sense magnetic fields. Mainly you'll get asked "*why?*" rather than "*hey can you save my friend with your powers?*".

Comment: If voltage does not matter, then the physiological change does not need to be as drastic.  That helps.

Comment: @DeveloperWeeks Oh, it needs to be incredibly drastic. Very small currents inside of people kill them in short order. When you get shocked by static from your sweater you're getting *thousands of volts* but very very small current. If you get just a few milliamps through your arms though, it can stop your heart. A magnetic field from a few milliamps is not enough to lift a paperclip.

Comment: So in summary, this answer is "human would die before accomplishing anything close without magic"

Comment: @DeveloperWeeks Correct, and it can even be generalized. Any known form of life would die before accomplishing anything close without magic.